# Xcode Archive automatically selects an iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to archive my app and I set the device to "Any iOS Device" but when I select archive it switches back to a simulator device. I am unsure how to resolve this.

Starts here:

[image: Starts here]

Defaults to this after clicking archive

[image]

Comment: That isn't a simulator device. It is your connected iPhone.  Xcode will automatically select your device if it is connected.  It doesn't matter what device you have selected when you archive, as long as it isn't a simulator. If you don't want it to select your phone, unplug it.

Comment: Xcode 15 will switch to the device remotely, so even if unplugged and starting to archive on 'any', it will switch mid way. Anyway, doesn't really matters.